# Включение простой базы данных в проект для работы через запросы (SqlConnection, SqlCommand)

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, visual-studio, sql-server

Visual Studio 2016.
Я пока умею работать с базой данных только так: создаю базу данных в (localDb)\Projects, генерю таблицы из файла со скриптом sql, потом вытаскиваю или записываю данные с помощью SqlCommand.
А включается ли она в проект, чтобы программа работала на другом компе? У меня что-то сомнения возникли.
[image: Обозревать объектов SQL Server с моей БД]

Если не включается, то объясните пожалуйста на пальцах для такого дубины, как я - возможно ли создать локальную БД внутри проекта, чтобы можно было с ней точно также работать запросами?
Если тыкнуть "Создать элемент", есть три варианта, "БД, основанная на службах", "Локальная БД", "Набор данных". Каждый из вариантов предполагает кучу разных настроек, которые мне по-моему нафиг не сдались. Думал, раз мне нужна локальная база, то вариант "Локальная БД" - самый логичный. Но не так всё просто.
Глянул "Набор данных" - сходу увидел, что там не запросы, и закрыл. Если выбрать локальную, то там еще 2 варианта - "Набор данных", "Модель данных EDM". То, что здесь опять есть набор данных - сбивает меня с толку. Модель данных у меня долго создавалась, но там надо собственно рисовать модель, что мне не нужно.
Короче, я что-то ни фига не понял, помогите пожалуйста дураку.
[image: "ПКМ на проекте-> Добавить -> Создать элемент..."]
[image: Диалоговое окно после выбора варианта "Локальная БД"]

Comment: Думаю стоит по гуглить codefirst ([например](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/jj193542.aspx))  или вот [это](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399420(v=vs.110).aspx) может помочь

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки, только ни намёка на работу с запросами ни там, ни там : /

Comment: Если использовать MS SQL LocalDB, то на чистом компе нужно будет установить: SQL Server Express LocalDB, .NET Framewokr, Ваша программа. Если ничего не хочется ставить кроме программы, думаю можно посмотреть в сторону SQLite

Answer (score 5):

1. Создаем проект;
2. <kbd>Источники данных</kbd> - <kbd>Добавить новый источник данных</kbd>;
3. <kbd>База данных</kbd> - <kbd>Набор данных</kbd> - <kbd>Создать подключение</kbd>, вводим имя файла базы данных. (*Использовать аутентификацию Windows*). Отмечаем галочкой *Да, сохранить подключение как* - *Готово*;

Вот у вас есть пустая локальная база данных подключенная к вашему приложению.
При компиляции файл вашей бд будет скопирован в папку с вашей программой.

В *Обозревателе баз данных* появляется ваша база данных. Выбираете ее, нажимаете правой кнопкой мыши, в меню выбираете *Новый запрос*. Там выполняете ваш `sql` скрипт по созданию структуры базы. Либо сами ручками, открываете подпапку *Таблицы*, *Хранимые процедуры*, *Представления* и т.п. и там создаете все что необходимо.

После этого в *Источнике данных* выбираете: *Настроить источник данных с помощью мастера*, там будет показана ваша бд. Отмечаете галочками необходимые таблицы, которые вам нужны в программе. После они появляются в виде дерева в источнике данных. Можно взять любую таблицу или отдельный ее столбец и перетянуть на форму. При этом автоматом создастся подключение необходимых компонентов для отображения данных.